# how to view the only one record based on primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

Registration table i inserted one record with `primaryID` is `DoctorID`

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [DoctorID]
      ,[DoctorSource]
      ,[Tittle]
      ,[DoctorName]
      ,[DoctorCode]
      ,[RegistrationNo]
      ,[Gender]
      ,[DocDOB]
      ,[DocAddress1]
      ,[DocAddress2]
      ,[Country]
      ,[State]
      ,[City]
      ,[Pincode]
      ,[CountryCode]
      ,[Mobile]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Website]
      ,[AadhaarCardNo]
      ,[Language]
      ,[AboutDoctor]
      ,[Status]
      ,[IPAddress]
      ,[Latitude]
      ,[Longitude]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [VAN_DOCTOR].[dbo].[DoctorRegistration]
```

[image: Registration]

Based on a `DoctorID` we inserted two records in experience table where Primary key is`ExperienceID` Reference key is `DoctorID`

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ExperienceID]
      ,[DoctorID]
      ,[HospitalName]
      ,[Department]
      ,[Designation]
      ,[FromDate]
      ,[ToDate]
      ,[WorkDescription]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [VAN_DOCTOR].[dbo].[Doctorexperience]
```

[image: Experience]

In my view page showing two records but we having only one `doctorID` So

I need to view only one records How to solve this

```
USE [VAN_DOCTOR]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetFullDoctorMEDEIL]    Script Date: 25-Oct-17 2:18:08 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetFullDoctorMEDEIL]  
as  
begin  
   select 

        DR.[DoctorID],
        DR.[DoctorSource],
        DR.[Tittle],
        DR.[DoctorName],
        DR.[DoctorCode],
        DR.[RegistrationNo],
        DR.[Gender],
        DR.[DocDOB],
        DR.[DocAddress1],
        DR.[DocAddress2],
        C.CountryName,
        S.StateName,
        DR.[City],
        DR.[Pincode],
        C.CountryCode + C.DialingCode As Countrydial,
        DR.[Mobile],
        DR.[Phone],
        DR.[Email],
        DR.[Website],
        DR.[AadhaarCardNo],
        DR.[Language],
        DR.[AboutDoctor],
        DR.[Status],

        DEX.[ExperienceID],
        DEX.[HospitalName],
        DEX.[Department],
        DEX.[Designation],
        DEX.[FromDate],
        DEX.[ToDate],
        DEX.[WorkDescription],

        DE.[DoctorEducationID],
        DE.[Qualification],
        DE.[Major],
        DE.[YearOfPassing],
        DE.[Institute],

        DC.[DoctorinformationID],
        DC.[CHospitalName],
        DC.[Address1],
        DC.[Address2],
        CD.CountryName,
        SD.StateName,
        DC.[CCity],
        DC.[CPincode],
        DC.[DoctorRoomNo],
        DC.[Consultingfees],
        SY.SpecialityName,
        CY.SpecialistName,

        DB.[BusinessDaysID],
        DB.[Sunday],
        DB.[Monday],
        DB.[Tuesday],
        DB.[Wednesday],
        DB.[Thursday],
        DB.[Friday],
        DB.[Saturday],
        DB.[SunStartTime],
        DB.[SunEndTime],
        DB.[MonStartTime],
        DB.[MonEndTime],
        DB.[TueStartTime],
        DB.[TueEndTime],
        DB.[WedStartTime],
        DB.[WedEndTime],
        DB.[ThuStartTime],
        DB.[ThuEndTime],
        DB.[FriStartTime],
        DB.[FriEndTime],
        DB.[SatStartTime],
        DB.[SatEndTime],

        DS.[DoctorSocialID],
        DS.[FaceBookID],
        DS.[TwitterID],
        DS.[linkedinID],
        DS.[PinterestID],
        DS.[GooglePlusID],


        DR.[CreatedDate]




        from DoctorRegistration AS DR


        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[Country] C ON C.CountryID=DR.Country
        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[State] S ON S.StateID=DR.State
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Doctorexperience] as DEX ON DEX.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DoctorEducation] as DE ON DE.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DoctorclinicInformation] as DC ON DC.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID

        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[Country] CD ON CD.CountryID=DC.CCountry
        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[State] SD ON SD.StateID=DC.CState

        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[Specialist] CY ON CY.SpecialistID=DC.SpecialistID
        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[Speciality] SY ON SY.SpecialityID=DC.SpecialityID

        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ClinicBusinessHour] as DB ON DB.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID

        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Doctorsocialnetwork] as DS ON DS.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID


End
```

[image: View]

Comment: Why the `C#` tag? Is that a mistake?

Comment: No sir i removed Sorry sir @Equalsk

Comment: The question is too long IMO.  Can you pare it down a bit?

Comment: Which experience record should your view show and why?  Milot hospital or Apollo hospital?

Comment: I want to view one one record based on DoctorID.then i click view doctor details page that time view two hospital records @GarethD

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYCjO.png  See in my picture @GarethD

Comment: Showing Only one record

Comment: But **why** should it show Apollo hospital rather than Milot? Why is that the correct record, and Milot not correct?

Comment: @GarethD In dashboard i need to display only one records but details page    all the information need to view both apollo hospital and milot hospital

Comment: I understand the problem. You have two records and only want one, this is not a difficult concept, but you need a way of choosing one of these, either the first alphabetically, or the earliest in time etc. I am just asking how you decide which of the two records to show.

Answer (score 1):

That's cause you have multiple records with same `DoctorId` and if I see the final query result with `JOIN`, both the resulted records are same and in that case you can probably use `distinct` like

```
   select distinct
        DR.[DoctorID],
        DR.[DoctorSource],
        DR.[Tittle],
        DR.[DoctorName],
```

You can as well use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) analytic function to get only one record out of those duplicates

```
select * from (
   select 
        DR.[DoctorID],
        DR.[DoctorSource],
        DR.[Tittle],
        DR.[DoctorName],
        DR.[DoctorCode],
        DR.[RegistrationNo],
        DR.[Gender],
        DR.[DocDOB],
        DR.[DocAddress1],
        DR.[DocAddress2],
        C.CountryName,
        S.StateName,
        DR.[City],
        DR.[Pincode],
        C.CountryCode + C.DialingCode As Countrydial,
        DR.[Mobile],
        DR.[Phone],
        DR.[Email],
        DR.[Website],
        DR.[AadhaarCardNo],
        DR.[Language],
        DR.[AboutDoctor],
        DR.[Status],

        DEX.[ExperienceID],
        DEX.[HospitalName],
        DEX.[Department],
        DEX.[Designation],
        DEX.[FromDate],
        DEX.[ToDate],
        DEX.[WorkDescription],

        DE.[DoctorEducationID],
        DE.[Qualification],
        DE.[Major],
        DE.[YearOfPassing],
        DE.[Institute],

        DC.[DoctorinformationID],
        DC.[CHospitalName],
        DC.[Address1],
        DC.[Address2],
        CD.CountryName,
        SD.StateName,
        DC.[CCity],
        DC.[CPincode],
        DC.[DoctorRoomNo],
        DC.[Consultingfees],
        SY.SpecialityName,
        CY.SpecialistName,

        DB.[BusinessDaysID],
        DB.[Sunday],
        DB.[Monday],
        DB.[Tuesday],
        DB.[Wednesday],
        DB.[Thursday],
        DB.[Friday],
        DB.[Saturday],
        DB.[SunStartTime],
        DB.[SunEndTime],
        DB.[MonStartTime],
        DB.[MonEndTime],
        DB.[TueStartTime],
        DB.[TueEndTime],
        DB.[WedStartTime],
        DB.[WedEndTime],
        DB.[ThuStartTime],
        DB.[ThuEndTime],
        DB.[FriStartTime],
        DB.[FriEndTime],
        DB.[SatStartTime],
        DB.[SatEndTime],

        DS.[DoctorSocialID],
        DS.[FaceBookID],
        DS.[TwitterID],
        DS.[linkedinID],
        DS.[PinterestID],
        DS.[GooglePlusID],

        DR.[CreatedDate],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DR.[DoctorID] ORDER BY DR.[DoctorID]) as rn



        from DoctorRegistration AS DR


        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[Country] C ON C.CountryID=DR.Country
        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[State] S ON S.StateID=DR.State
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Doctorexperience] as DEX ON DEX.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DoctorEducation] as DE ON DE.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DoctorclinicInformation] as DC ON DC.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID

        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[Country] CD ON CD.CountryID=DC.CCountry
        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[State] SD ON SD.StateID=DC.CState

        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[Specialist] CY ON CY.SpecialistID=DC.SpecialistID
        LEFT JOIN [VAN_SETTING].[dbo].[Speciality] SY ON SY.SpecialityID=DC.SpecialityID

        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ClinicBusinessHour] as DB ON DB.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID

        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Doctorsocialnetwork] as DS ON DS.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID ) tt
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: am a new in this technology please sir help me@Rahul

Comment: In dashboard i need to display only one records but details page all the information need to view both apollo hospital and milot hospital @Rahul

Comment: @IvinRaj, *In dashboard i need to display only one record* ... what is that one record you wanted to show. clarify that in your post

Comment: Then you you need one query just from `DoctorRegistration` for the dashboard, then you use your other (two record) query to list all the info in the details page. OR you use the query that returns two records, and just display the first record in your summary. Note that in your example, picture _it is only showing one record!_

Comment: https://ibb.co/hdAy5m See this is my dashboard page view three records.. Same DoctorId repeat two records see

Comment: See i inserted two experience id but view one id

Comment: For the picture at https://ibb.co/hdAy5m.. you need to use a select _just_ from `DoctorRegistration`. You should not join to the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you join Doctorexperience you will have as many record as in this table. If there will be one record in DoctorRegistration and 5 records in Doctorexperience you will get 5 records with joining. Distinct will not help becouse you are getting ExperienceID column from Doctorexperience and it is primary key. Maybe you need only first record from Doctorexperience  so you can do something like that instead of join Doctorexperience:

```
OUTER APPLY 
(
  select top 1 DEX.ExperienceID, ... from [dbo].[Doctorexperience]  DEX
   where DEX.DoctorID=DR.DoctorID
) EXTOP
```